# Syntax Error In Insert Statement SQL C#

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm having trouble with the `df.ExecuteNonQuery();` claiming that the insert statement has SQL errors. I'm not sure why the other parts of the program is working with the Insert statement, but the student one just refuses to work. 

Database: http://puu.sh/hoTCv/c1ccb77551.png

```
OleDbCommand df = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Students(ID,Password,FirstName,LastName,Street,City,State,Zip,EMail,GPA)" + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", db);
//creating parameters
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", iDText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PassText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", fnText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LnText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street", StreetText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", CityText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", StateText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", ZipText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMail", EmailText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GPA", GPAText.Text);
df.ExecuteNonQuery();
db.Close();
```

Comment: `Password` is a *reserved* keyword. It must be escape `[Password]`.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can this:

```
INSERT into Students(ID,Password ....
```

To this:

```
INSERT into Students(ID,[Password] ....
```

Comment: @Sorry Don't forget to mark it as an answer, if it helped you. This way you will give reputation to person, who helped you

Comment: Yes, I can't mark a answer into 9 minutes after its been asked.

Answer (score 1):

`Password` is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266?wa=wsignin1.0) in Microsoft OLE DB Provider. You need to use square brackets like `[Password]`. As a best practice, change your column name to *non-reserved* word.

Also don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected results](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` overloads to specify your [`OleDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) and your parameter size.

And would be better to use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` automatically instead calling `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` methods manually.

Answer (score 0):

`Password` is a reserved keyword. Wrap your password like `[Password]`

> Microsoft SQL Server uses reserved keywords for defining,
>   manipulating, and accessing databases. Reserved keywords are part of
>   the grammar of the Transact-SQL language that is used by SQL Server to
>   parse and understand Transact-SQL statements and batches. Although it
>   is syntactically possible to use SQL Server reserved keywords as
>   identifiers and object names in Transact-SQL scripts, you can do this
>   only by using delimited identifiers.